# Resnick - Probability Path - Exercise 6.12 (b)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm struggling to solve the following problem from Resnick's book:

> If for some $p>0$
>
> $\frac{|X_{n}|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} \xrightarrow{P}0$
> holds, then $X_{n}\xrightarrow{P}0$.

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show that, for any $\epsilon>0$, $\Pr(|X_n|>\epsilon)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

For a given $\epsilon$, let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon^p}{1+\epsilon^p}>0$. If 
 $\frac{|X_{n}|^p}{1+|X_n|^p}$ converges, then $\Pr(\frac{|X_{n}|^p}{1+|X_n|^p}>\delta)\to 0$.
You can check that $\frac{|X_{n}|^p}{1+|X_n|^p}>\delta$ is equivalent to $|X_n|>\epsilon$, so you are done.

Comment: I can't see why $\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} >δ$  is equivalent to $|X_n|>ϵ$, since we're dealing with probabilities. My initial idea was trying to break $\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} $ in two parts so I could use one of the properties: $X_n+Y_n \xrightarrow{P} X+Y $ or $X_n\times Y_n \xrightarrow{P} X\times Y $, but it didn't work out.

Comment: Is equivalent as an event: $\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} >δ$ is $\frac{|X_n|^p}{1+|X_n|^p} >\frac{\epsilon^p}{1+\epsilon^p}$,  i.e. $ (1+\epsilon^p)|X_n|^p>\epsilon^p(1+|X_n|^p)$, then simplify the last expression to get the result.

Comment: Got it now! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the function defined on $[0,+\infty)$ by $x\mapsto x^p/\left(1+x^p\right)$ is non-decreasing hence the inclusion 
$$
\left\{\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert \geqslant\varepsilon\right\}\subseteq\left\{\frac{\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert^p}{1+\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert^p} \geqslant\frac{\varepsilon^p}{1+\varepsilon^p}\right\}
$$
holds.